# MySQL trigger 'update on column' syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, sql-update

Can we use a MySQL trigger on update of specific columns, which updates another column in same table (same row)

```
create trigger my_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF col1, col2 ON TABLE_NAME
for each row
set NEW.col3 =  NEW.col3 +1;
```

I tried the above code using `UPDATE OF col1, col2` . It is not working in MySQL. What is the correct syntax, can somebody point me to some examples.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't specify that the trigger is to be run only on the update of specific columns (an `UPDATE` affects the entire record), but you can test which columns have been updated within your trigger:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_NAME FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (NEW.col1 <=> OLD.col1 AND NEW.col2 <=> OLD.col2) THEN
  SET NEW.col3 = NEW.col3 + 1;
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this just specific to mysql?

Comment: @ms1020: What other RDBMS are you interested in?

Comment: Right now I can only use mysql. Just wanted to know if any other RDBMS has this limitation. I know ORACLE supports on column update.