# MySQL Trigger: Update next row timestamp

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I would like to update next row's timestamp, when I update current row's `Ready`-column.

As example, I will

```
UPDATE `Projects` SET `Ready` = 1 WHERE `Id` = 1
```

that should to fire trigger seen below

```
UPDATE `Projects` SET `Started` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `Id` = `Id` + 1
```

But how to make this happen using MySQL's `TRIGGER`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, because, when you your trigger fires, it updates the same table and would cause to fire the same trigger again, causing an endless recursion.

Comment: But is it possible to fire trigger only when column `Ready` is changed?

Comment: No, this is not possible with mysql, AFAIK. But look at [MySQL trigger 'update on column' syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356967/mysql-trigger-update-on-column-syntax), this might solve your problem.