# Creating an immutable field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'd like to make a `TIMESTAMP` field `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, for 'creation time' purpose. But if someone or somehow something changes that `TIMESTAMP,` my data won't be consistent.

Is there a way I can ensure it won't change unless I delete the row and reinsert it, other than application level?

---

With the suggested answer provided, i could work around with something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER consistency1 BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.creationtime != OLD.creationtime THEN
       SET NEW.creationtime = OLD.creationtime;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I don't think that it's possible, but maybe you can figure out a workaround with a trigger-before-update

Comment: Agreed with @STTLCU. I found this here (previous value check and overwrite): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356967/mysql-trigger-update-on-column-syntax

Comment: @Rolice thank you, i've added the link you provided in my answer

Comment: The answers are fiddly workarounds at best, but really just potential bugs waiting to happen. Forcing some field to be reverted or not updated based on some trigger or hacky FK on another table is just to be avoided. Instead, make sure devs who have access to make changes are just clued up, and code reviews are actioned in a concise manner to catch potential bad updates. Like "hey, why are you updating this auto inc ID on this table..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since my comment has been appreciated, here's the extended version.

I personally don't think that it's possible.

Anyway, there are a couple of things you can try:

1. Make sure that only your application can write on the database
2. Write a trigger like this (pseudocode!)

   ```
   create trigger prevent_change_timestamp on tbl_name
   before update
   #fetch old row value
   #verify if the timestamp field has been changed
   #raise an error (any SQL error will do)
   ```
3. Or like this

   ```
   create trigger revert_change_timestamp on tbl_name
   after update
   #fetch pre-change row value
   #update the row with the "old" value in place of the new one
   ```

I'd personally go with the 3rd option, if possible. Anyway, the 2nd one is good too. I'd not rely on the 1st option unless necessary (eg: no access to trigger functionality)

More info here: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356967/mysql-trigger-update-on-column-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

It's funny in a way that database apps don't offer this functionality as standard: not only for a "created" timestamp field, but for things like autoincrement id fields, and any miscellaneous values which you may want to set on creating a record and then never allow to be changed... wonder what the rationale is?

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by citing some sources that "database apps don't offer this functionality as standard".

Comment: @Lee It's a bit meaningless and laborious to find and cite sources to prove something that is common knowledge. The very existence of this question and the answers is because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is, you can write a `TRIGGER` on the table when a row is being updated. In that trigger, you can compare the old and new values, and if they are different then you can just overwrite the new value with the old one.

Comment: Triggers are the devil's playchild.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in MySQL 5.1 and got an error

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER member_update_0
    ->     AFTER UPDATE ON members
    ->     FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.id != OLD.id THEN
    ->        SET NEW.id = OLD.id;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
```

ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

The same trigger with AFTER replaced by BEFORE is accepted;
to me, this is a counter-intuitive way to do it, but it works

```
delimiter ;
UPDATE members SET id=11353 WHERE id=1353;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: With an AFTER trigger, the change has already been made and you are saying, "you just made a change? Okay, let me do something based on that". With a BEFORE trigger, you are *intervening beforehand*, saying, "you're about to make a change? Hold up, what change are you going to make? I might want you to do some things beforehand and/or make a different change instead." If you wanted to use an AFTER trigger to alter a change that has just been made, you would need to use an UPDATE query, but then two UPDATE queries are actually being run: the original one, and the subsequent one in your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to do this very neatly if you are using InnoDB.

Create another table with just one column. That column should have a foreign key (hence the innodb requirement in this solution) that points to the immutable column of the original table in question.

Put a restriction like "ON UPDATE RESTRICT".

In summary:

```
CREATE TABLE original (
     ....
     immutable_column ...
     INDEX index1(immutable_column)
     ....
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE restricter (
     .....
     col1,
     INDEX index2(col1),
     FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES original (immutable_colum) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Although having a trigger is not ideal I think that adding a whole table just to enforce immutability is not an elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Taking the idea a step further (for those of us still stuck with a legacy version of MySQL) you can have BOTH a protected & defaulted create_stamp AND an auto-updating update_stamp as follows:

If you have a table such as

```
CREATE TABLE `csv_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_stamp` datetime not null,
  `update_stamp` timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,
  `status` enum('happy','sad') not null default 'happy'
);
```

Then you can define these triggers on it

```
drop trigger if exists set_create_stamp ;
create definer = CURRENT_USER trigger set_create_stamp BEFORE INSERT on 
csv_status for each row
  set NEW.create_stamp = now();

drop trigger if exists protect_create_stamp ;
delimiter //
create definer = CURRENT_USER trigger protect_create_stamp BEFORE UPDATE on 
csv_status for each row
  begin
    if NEW.create_stamp != OLD.create_stamp then
    set NEW.create_stamp = OLD.create_stamp;
    end if;
  end;//
delimiter ;
```